# Free multiple selection calendar

Tags: asp.net, calendar

Does anybody know a free ASP.NET control that allow to select multiple dates ?

I'd like something like the [classic ASP.NET DateTime picker](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) but with multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use (but not ASP.NET control) the [YUI calendar](https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/).

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with Kelvin Luck's [jQuery date picker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/) in the past. It's not super sexy, but it works well.